# enumeration can not be created

Tags: java, enums, enumeration

I am trying to create the below enumeration, but Eclipse gives the following error:

> Syntax error, insert ";" to complete ClassBodyDeclarations

Code:

```
public class SE {

    private enum Separator {
        COMMA(","),
        SEMICOLON(";"),
        COLON(":");

        private String separator;
    }

}
```

**update**:

```
//still receiving the same error

public class ParameterParser {

private enum Separator {

    COMMA(","),
    SEMICOLON(";"),
    COLON(":");

    private String mSeparator;

    private Separator(String separator) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.mSeparator = separator;
    }

    public String getSeparator() {
        return this.mSeparator;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a constructor

```
private Separator(String separator) {
    this.separator = separator;
}
```

Comment: almost simultaniously! ;)

Comment: remove the `void` keyword as shown in the answer :)

Comment: eclipse does not allow me to introduce Separator as constructor, when I remove the keyword void it suggests to set constructor of ParameterParser instead

Comment: every opened bracket has a correponding closing one...as shown in my updated code for the 2nd timmes

Comment: just paste the answer into your original class. i.e. get it working - you can do refactoring improvements afterwards :)

Comment: i am wondering i am still having the error..am i missing an import??

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the constructor for the enum!

```
private Separator (String s) {
    separator = s;
}
```

**update:**

```
public class ParameterParser {

    private enum Separator {

        COMMA(","),
        SEMICOLON(";"),
        COLON(":");

        private String mSeparator;

        private Separator(String separator) {
            this.mSeparator = separator;
        }

        public String getSeparator() {
            return this.mSeparator;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Separator comma = Separator.COMMA;
        Separator semic = Separator.SEMICOLON;
        Separator colon = Separator.COLON;

        System.out.println(comma + ": " + comma.getSeparator());
        System.out.println(semic + ": " + semic.getSeparator());
        System.out.println(colon + ": " + colon.getSeparator());
    }
}
```

This code compiles fine and outputs:

```
COMMA: ,
SEMICOLON: ;
COLON: :
```

So if you're still having problems with this code, ist must be something else! You'll have to give us more information (e.g. maybe Separator is already defined, more code in the ParameterParser class etc.)

Comment: eclipse does not allow me to introduce Separator as constructor, when I remove the keyword void it suggests to set constructor of ParameterParser  instead

Comment: you were also missing one closing bracket... the code as it is in my update works for me!

Comment: every opened bracket has a correponding closing one...as shown in my updated code for the 2nd timmes

Comment: i am wondering i am still having the error..am i missing an import??

Comment: you don't have to import anything for creating an enum.